# UIButton addTarget crashes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I want to make a UIButton call a method in my tableView controller but it crashes every time I press that said button.

This button is located in my cell that as a custom class but I want the action of the button to be done in my tableviewController so I decided to add this code in the "cellForRowAtIndex" method:

```
cell.DeleteFromDevice.tag = 10;
[cell.DeleteFromDevice addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteVideos:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It is suppose to call the following method:

```
-(void)deleteVideos:(UIButton*)sender
```

What do I do wrong ? Can I make something like that or not ?

here is the error log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[VideoTableViewController DeleteVideo:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fabbfe38720'
```

Comment: `@selector(deleteVideos)` => `@selector(deleteVideos:)` (with the semicolons)? But strangely, the error message says it has the one starting with an uppercase. Strange. Also don't name your variable starting with an uppercase like `DeleteFromDevice` is should be `deleteFromDevice` at least.

Comment: My bad I didn't saw that.. But it is still not working even with the ":".     Ok thanks for the advise

Comment: But the error says it has it: `[VideoTableViewController DeleteVideo:]`. I guess that you connected it in Storyboard then? Remove it.

Comment: `DeleteVideo` isn't linked in any .h file involved in this. `DeleteFromDevice` is linked by storyboard to the .h file of my cell as an outlet.

Comment: Thanks @Larme You were right I did check the linking of the button and it had touchUpinside linked to it ! now it doesn't crash anymore